# Componente ui:composition do JSF não funciona

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2.2

Estou criando um template de exemplo porém quando a página abre fica em branco, segue o template e página que tenta puxar o template:

master-template.xhtml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title><ui:insert name="titulo">Sistema de livraria on-line</ui:insert></title>
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="sistema.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
<div id="conteudo">
    <ui:insert name="corpo" />
</div>
</h:body>
<p:separator style="margin-top: 20px" />
<footer> Exemplo de Template - <a href="#" target="_blank">www.exemplo.com.br</a>
```

```
</html>
```

exemplo.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
template="/WEB-INF/template/master-template.xhtml ">

<ui:define name="conteudo">Exemplo 2</ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

E quando a página abre ela fica exibindo somente "Exemplo2" e olhando o código fonte que gerou no navegador ele fica desse jeito:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" template="/WEB-INF/template/master-template.xhtml ">
<ui:define name="conteudo">Exemplo 2</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Na sua *template* principal, você declarou um elemento HTML `div#conteudo` e definiu que o **JSF** vai renderizar uma área identificada pelo nome `corpo` dentro desse elemento, conforme pode ser verificado no arquivo **master-template.xhtml**:

```
<div id="conteudo">
    <ui:insert name="corpo" />
</div>
```

No entanto, na hora de utilizar a *template*, você faz a definição (**ui:define**) de uma área identificada com o nome de `conteudo`, conforme pode ser verificado no seu arquivo **exemplo.xhtml**:

```
<ui:define name="conteudo">Exemplo 2</ui:define>
```

Na hora de renderizar a sua página, o **JSF** recebeu uma área identificada pelo nome `conteudo` mas não recebeu nenhuma instrução de como renderizar a mesma.

Recomendo a leitura do seguinte material, que deixa bem claro essa explicação: [`JSF 2 Templating with Facelets example`](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/)